# How to run a function on dataframe using character of dataframe's name?

Tags: r

I have 30 dataframes called Z1 to Z30. I want to run a function on each of them. How can I run it using a vector of dataframes names `paste0("Z", 1:30)`?

Comment: You may use functions like `Map` or `purrr::map`

Comment: If they are all similarly structured, I suggest you change your methodology to a [list of tables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/3358227), at which point `lapply(my_list_of_frames, function(z) {...})` is all you would need.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You can get `my_list_of_frames` mentioned in @r2evans  comment using `my_list_of_frames <- mget(paste0("Z", 1:30))` which is also mentioned in the same answer.

Comment: Thank you all! List of tables could be helpful but basically get() and mget() functions was all I needed. Thank you @RonakShah

Comment: Just a hint: avoid `get()` + `assign()` structures. If you are going to do something like this, use a list instead.

Comment: @MartinGal why should I avoid using get() and assign()?